# Dynamic linking to Wordpress database

Tags: wordpress

I intend to use WP to setup a freelancers website (similar to oDesk) to connect service providers with service seekers in a WEB 2.0 dynamic environment. This site requires multiple forms to enter and retrieve information using database and show them in filtered or non-filtered views in separate pages.

Please advise if there are available plugins to expedite developing this site, or otherwise any guidance would be appreciated. I specifically would like to know how to connect forms to database and then how to retrieve this information from the DB.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You are likely going to have to create your own custom WordPress theme, using various custom PHP pages to connect your web forms to your database. I think your project is well beyond the scope of a simple WP plugin.

If this was my project, I'd ditch WordPress and go for something custom built in Rails. WordPress is a good enough CMS, but it isn't really a good fit for what you are looking to accomplish.